# Бдеть бдить, снабдить

Tags: орфография, словообразование

Почему у слова снабд**и**ть на конце пишется "и", хотя оно вроде образовано от глагола бд**е**ть, тогда как бд**и**ть вроде бы вообще отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

На чем основано утверждение, что форма «бдеть» не имеет варианта «бдить»? По числу вхождений в КРЯ (34 против 18) преимуществ формы «бдеть» не наблюдается. Существование варианта «бдить» подтверждают слова: «бди», «бдит», «бдим», «бдительно» и пр.

"Хороша наша жизнь ― напоит допьяна, 
Карамелью снабдит, удивит каруселью… 
[С. М. Гандлевский. «Чикиликанье галок в осеннем дворе...» (1981)]"

"Помилуйте, мы рады сами
Снабдить вас прочными мозгами, 
Но нас валюта не влечет: 
Мы вас умом снабдим за счет
Уюта, удовлетворенности…
[И. В. Елагин. Разговор продавца с покупателем (1967-1973)]"

В этих примерах из КРЯ фигурируют слова «снабдит» (сна+бдит) и «снабдим» (сна+бдим). Однако не стоит удивляться, что в русском языке уже есть слова: бдительный, снабженец снабжает, но (пока еще) не встречаются ни «снабдительный», ни «бженец», ни «бжает».